# Equivalent ways of writing the log-likelihood of a sample of normal RVs

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I am going through my econometrics textbook right now and the textbook writes the log-likelihood equation for a sample of normal random variables in a way I have never seen before. Specifically, for a sample of $x_1...x_n$ random variables where $x_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, . They write as follows:

(1) $\text{ln }l_t(0, \sigma^2)= -{1\over2}\text{ln}(2\pi)-{1\over2}\text{ln}(\sigma^2)-{1\over{2\sigma^2n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx^2$

I am used to seeing the log-likelihood of a general collection of normal variables written as:

(2) $\text{ln }l_t(\mu, \sigma^2)= -{n\over2}\text{ln}(2\pi)-{n\over2}\text{ln}(\sigma^2)-{1\over{2\sigma^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n(x-\mu)^2$

And when $\mu=0$, that implies:

(3) $\text{ln }l_t(0, \sigma^2)= -{n\over2}\text{ln}(2\pi)-{n\over2}\text{ln}(\sigma^2)-{1\over{2\sigma^2}}\sum_{i=1}^nx^2$

I cannot see how equations (1) and (3) are equivalent. Seems like some algebra trick that I'm not getting. Any ideas?

Comment: They are not equivalent.  (1) is wrong.  It will give the correct estimate (because it is $1/n$ times a correct log likelihood) *but it will not give correct covariances, confidence intervals, or prediction intervals.*

Comment: the first one is the second one divided by $n$ and, as whuber said, it ( the first one ) is not correct but it won't matter for maximization.